# Centralness of planar convex regions - behavior under projective transformations

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, projective-geometry

**Background:**
For a planar convex region $C$ and an interior point $P$ we define:

- the *centralness ratio* at $P$ is
  $$\min\left(\frac{\text{shorter portion of }\chi}{\text{longer portion of }\chi}:\chi\text{ is a chord of }C\text{ through }P\right)$$
  The interior point that maximizes this ratio can be called the center of $C$ and the value of the ratio there, the centralness of the region $C$. It is known that centralness is a minimum of 1/2 if and only if $C$ is a triangle.
- It appears that when any affine transformation is done to any $C$, the image of the center is the new center and the centralness is unaltered.

**Question:** How does centralness and center behave under projective transformations? If $C$ is any convex quadrilateral, we can change centralness at will with projective transformations - and arbitrarily approach 1/2. But given a general convex n-gon, how could one (say) algorithmically maximize(or minimize) the centralness thru a suitable projective transformation?

For example, given some general convex hexagon(say), one could try to transform it projectively so that the centralness of the resulting polygon is the maximum or minimum possible.